# how to add google map as a ui component in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, google-map

I need to display a coordinated field, coming from the database, currently am displaying it as an input like this:

[image]

I need to display it as the map like this:

[image]

I googled a LOT and lot of answers on how to load the map using requireJS, but is not working with Magento 2.1...

***help pleaaaaase***

Comment: Check  my updated answer and let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 3):

Add new field with `<item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/form/elements/googlemap</item>`

```
<field name="googlemap">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/form/elements/googlemap</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Google Map</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">popup</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">googlemap</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Create `googlemap.html` at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/elements/googlemap.html

and add `<iframe>` of google map in **googlemap.html**

```
<div>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d235013.7071737442!2d72.43965367078681!3d23.020497773009463!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x395e848aba5bd449%3A0x4fcedd11614f6516!2sAhmedabad%2C+Gujarat!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1504178551457" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to replace Namespace_Module with your module and vendor name.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: thanks.. and how to pass the coordinates to the map?

Comment: is there a way to use the Google map API , rather than i frame, the reason is to allow the admin to modify the value using the google map drag and drop