# how to display Google map on magento 2 admin side

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, magento2.3, google-map

actually, I want to use google map to get latitude and longitude of a place using google map so I need to use google map on backend using UI component form 
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/how-to-add-google-map-as-a-ui-component-in-magento-2-1

Comment: how can i store latitude and longitude

Comment: You will get lat and long from google api. Save it on your db for future use if needed.

Comment: ok sir i will look into it thanks for tour great help