# Magento 2 API to get all products with filter

Tags: magento2, rest-api

[image]I am working on an API where I need all product of Magento store. I am using postman to make a collection, but I am getting this error.
kindly tell me what is causing this error[image]

image with the [image]new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at `webapi.xml` you could see route of above mentioned api defined like this:

```
<route url="/V1/products" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

`ref="Magento_Catalog::products"` means that only users with configured ACL which allow access to this resource are allowed to get it. In magento ONLY admin user can have a configuration of ACL.

So that you will have to use `admin token` or `Integration token`

Get an admin token :

```
   Method:POST Endpoint: /V1/integration/admin/token
```

For More details refer this official documentation : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: now it shows message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.

Comment: i am adding screen shot

Comment: i got admin token but not product data

Comment: baseURL is in a variable {{baseurl}}

Comment: ok got it. you will have to mention the **searchcriteria**

Comment: See this : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html

Comment: ok, if I want all products then how it can be done can you please tell me in json format

Comment: Example `http://www.dexample.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1680&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89871/discussion-between-adarsh-shukla-and-nid).

Comment: For all products: /V1/products?searchCriteria

Comment: For 1000 products: /V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=1000

Comment: now it says product is required chack imag

Comment: do you have products?

Comment: Small correction try this for all products `V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=`

Comment: yes is i do have 3 products in my catalog

Comment: bro it is not POST. Its a GET

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.

Comment: can you help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260763/how-to-display-google-map-on-magento-2-admin-side

Comment: yeah i will look in to it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89874/discussion-on-answer-by-nid-magento-2-api-to-get-all-products-with-filter).

Answer (score 1):

```
baseurl/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[currentPage]=4&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10
```

Use above endpoint to eradicate the issue fieldName is a required field

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir I got the solution for this problem. can you please look for this problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260763/how-to-display-google-map-on-magento-2-admin-side

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Admin token in Headers. Below is docs to get Admin token in Maganto 2.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-admin-token.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir I got the solution for this problem. can you please look for this problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260763/how-to-display-google-map-on-magento-2-admin-side